# Disable iframe map zoom using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm including  third party url which implements google map. I want to disable mouse zoom, scroll and touch pad zoom, but still want to enable `+` and `-` for zoom in and zoom out.

Is there a way to disable zoom events for iframe map.

What i have done right now is, on scroll im adding class name `disable-map`

```
 $(window).on("scrollstart",function(e,a) {
    console.log('start');
    $('#map_iframe').addClass('disable-map');
});

$(window).on("scrollstop",function(e,a) {
    $('#map_iframe').removeClass('disable-map');
});

.disable-map {
   pointer-events : none; 
}
```

Is there any other better solutions.

Comment: and the third-party is....

Comment: Third party solution is developed by a different team internally.  Just want to  try from my side to disable events on scroll.

Other wise have to  go all the way through them, that's going to be time taking process.